# Programming an 82S23

Tags: programmer, eeprom, rom

I have to program an 82S23.

There is surprisingly little documentation on how to do this. There are datasheets that will tell you how to *read* it, but not burn.

I built one following [these](http://www.retrotechnology.com/dri/prom_shook.html) specifications, but after programming, the bit would stay low. In addition, application of the high programming voltages actually causes the PROM to heat up. I actually fried one by holding the program button down too long.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help you? http://gamearchive.askey.org/General/Data_Sheets/generic1_prom/

I searched for Signetics Generic 1 fusing procedure.

Also, according to the datasheet on the page I linked, the programming supply current is up to 500mA (at Vccp of 8.75V), and the current into the data pin being programmed is up to 200mA (at Vopf of 18V). So I would expect the chip might get warm, as it is dissipating almost 8W (8.75V*.5A + 18V*.2A).